# Windows Phone 7 Downloading Multiple Images

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, webclient

I am making a flexster like application for windows phone 7.5. I have a piece of code that I want to get upcoming movie pictures and movie Id. But when my code completes, only the first pictures get populated in the listbox Images. This is my code:

```
public void NowPlayinJson(string Uri)
{
  string apiUri = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}10", Uri, ApiKay, PagesLimit);
  WebClient Rclient = new WebClient();

  Rclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(apiUri));
  Rclient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
  {
      if (e.Error == null)
      {
          jsonStringValue = (e.Result.ToString().Trim());
          ImageUri();
       }
  };
}
public void ImageUri()
{
    var ParseImageUri = JObject.Parse(jsonStringValue);
    var ParseToJson = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject(ParseImageUri.ToString());

    NowPlayingUri = ParseToJson.movies[0+a].posters.detailed;

    a++;
    DownloadImage();
}


public void DownloadImage()
{
    if (!web.IsBusy)
    {
        web.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(NowPlayingUri), UriKind.Absolute);
    }
    web.OpenReadCompleted += 
        new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(web_OpenReadCompleted);
} 

void web_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        while(i<6)
        {
            var stream = e.Result;

            var bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(stream);

            myNowPlayingList.Add(new NowPlaying() 
                { NowImage = bi, NowTitle = "title" + i });
            i++;
            if (b < 6)
            {
                b++;
                ImageUri();
            }
            if(b == 6)
            {
                b++;
                NowPlayingListBox.ItemsSource = myNowPlayingList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not maintaining any `queue` or list for pending image downloads. Note that the `webClient can download one Image at a time`, so if its busy add it to a queue. On successful download check queue length. If its not empty, remove item from queue and add it to the webClient downloading. Also it would be wiser if you `maintain a cache` or something else similar to it, if image is already in Cache or IS, don't download and display from there itself else add the image to download queue. Hope this approach helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Milan. could you be kind enough to show me an example of a queue please. if you could that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See here [Queue](http://www.dotnetperls.com/queue). Use your custom datatype instead of <int> in the example.